# Database relationships - 1:1 but not always?

Tags: database, database-design, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Apologies for the fairly unhelpful title, if you have a better suggestion please feel free to edit it.

I'm using CakePHP and the bake functionality (I don't need to bake however).

What's the best way of achieving the following:

table schema:

```
table ranges   
id | name | description

table images
id | range_id | picture

table info (here i am confused)
id | range_id | height | width | colour
```

Basically, one range may have many images (1:Many). I can show this fine.

Now, each range will have an entry in the `info` table (1:1) and some attributes about the range such as height, colour, width. But not always...

Let's say I have a range `foo`. `foo` has five `images` that all have the same height, width and colour. However, `foo` has one image that is a different size and a different colour.

When the attributes differ, I need to show this information with the respective image, rather than the `ranges` *default* information. So this `image` will need it's own entry in the `info` table.

Does this even make sense? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way.

My application, in brief:
(If it helps, think of "range" as a product)

- User selects a range
- User views images in the range
- User can click an image, and the information from `info` pops up about that range.
- Some images have different attributes, but still belong to the same range.
- How can I make this distinction and store it appropriately?

Please let me know if I can clarify further. Thank you.

Comment: Why exactly aren't you storing height / width / colour in the images table?

Comment: @stevecomrie - good point, but the information is associated with the `range` rather than the `image`, except in the example highlighted. If I were to store the info with the image, I would have data redundancy in 9/10 cases. (In my current schema/set up at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've needed to do this on occasion where a parent entity has a value that can get "overridden" by a child entity.

There are a couple of approaches you can take the structure being the easiest part.
consider the following structure

```
table ranges   
id | name | description | default_info_id

table images
id | range_id | picture | info_id

table info
id | height | width | colour
```

When does image.info_id have a value? There are two choices

**Populate the image.info_id with the default_info_id from the parent.** The user can then override it on the image

**Pros**

- You never need to look at the Range to figure out what the info is on the image

**Cons**

- you need to decide what to do when the range.default_info_id changes. does it effect the images or is it just for future

**Only Populate the images.info_id when its different than the parent.**

**Pros**

- If the parents.default_info_id changes when images.info_id is null it will automatically change as well

**Cons**

- you need to decide what to do when the range.default_info_id changes. Do you need to now null out any images.info_id that are now the same as the parent?
- You need to look at the rages table to figure out what the info_id is on the images when its null.

You can have several varieties of the above data structures but you'll still need to figure when to populate what. Here are two others you could consider that are valid (but less optimal in my opinion)

**Info has an FK to both tables but one is always null**

```
table ranges   
id | name | description 

table images
id | range_id | picture 

table info
id | range_id | image_id | height | width | colour
```

**No Info Table at all**

```
table ranges   
id | name | description | default_height | default_width | default_colour

table images
id | range_id | picture | height | width | colour
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for such a detailed response. I think the first option will be better in the long run; will see how I get on.